# Firebase retrieve from array of keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a project, using Firebase, and I'm trying to get users whose IDs intersect with a provided array. While this is JavaScript, I've added the TypeScript types in order to make things a little easier to follow.

```
const getUsers = (userKeys: string[]) => {
  // for each ID in `userKeys`, go get that user
}
```

my data looks like the following:

```
{
  "qwertyuiop": {
    "firstName": "Bob",
    "lastName": "Test",
    "emailAddress": "bob@test.com",
  },
  "asdfghjkl": {
    "firstName": "Jake",
    "lastName": "Alsotest",
    "email": "jake@email.com",
  }
}
```

Obviously, I have much more data, but the goal is to provide an array of IDs to the `getUsers` function, and either make successive calls, or just batch get all the users where the IDs match. I have decent experience in Firebase, and for this project, we are using `firebase-admin`, and I have little-to-no experience using the admin SDK for JavaScript.

I've experimented using the Bluebird Promise library, but couldn't get past `[Promise { <Pending> }, Promise { <Pending> }]`, and, unfortunately, asynchronous code simply won't work here. I'm looking for advice on how to solve this problem, but I'm afraid I won't get anywhere.

I have tried the following implementations:

- mapping over each item in the `userKeys` array and performing:

  database
    .child('users')
    .child(key)
    .once('value', ...)
- same, but with `forEach`
- `Promise.map`
- `Promise.each`
- pushing each Promise to an array, and then returning `Promise.all`

Literally nothing seems to work. I'm at such a loss here...

Comment: Why won't async work?

Comment: @Wainage I'm under the constant impression that data looks completely different one clock cycle later, especially when it comes to database calls. I prefer promises, async/await, Promise.coroutine, or some other _safe_ method of retrieving data

Comment: Firebase doesn't query like a normal database. How much "user data" is in the db?

Comment: @Wainage couple thousand people at this time, which is why I'd rather filter by the IDs I actually need

Comment: Save yourself the headache. Make a call to your backend and have it filter the data and send it to a new location in the Firebase DB. Firebase "query's" are insanely limited

Comment: _sigh_ alright. I was afraid that'd be the case. No problem. Thanks for the help!